# Ruby : Use external script from within a script to do a comparison

Tags: ruby, comparison, ip

So I got a script (A) that finds a suitable IP address for a new virtual server. At first, it takes a look in the database to see if the first ip he chose isn't already taken by another server. If the IP is not already in use, the script pings it. If there is no response from the ping, then we get to the next step and this is where I'm having a problem.

In the next step, I have to check if the IP address is already registred in the netscaler (router) or not. To do this, I must use another script on the same machine (B). This other script return the list of all the ips defined in the netscaler. When I run it, the output looks like this

```
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x (and so on..).
```

I found many ways to execute the script B from whiting the script A, but none of what I found allow me to do what I'd like to.

My goal is to compare the ip my script found with all of those that are listed, without having those last ones printed on the screen.

So, to make it a bit clearer, let's say that the scrip A found the IP : 1.2.3.4

It would then call script B that would return to script A this list

1.2.3.5
1.2.4.5
1.2.5.1
and so on.

and then A would compare 1.2.3.4 with all those returned by script B without actually showing them on screen.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate `scriptB` business logic from `scriptB` ui (CLI) logic:

```
scriptA.rb
scriptB.rb
netscaler.rb # extract logic here
```

Extract your `list of all the ips defined in the netscaler` logic into separate class/method:

```
#netscaler.rb
class Netscaler
  def self.list_ips
    # return array of ips here
  end
end

#scriptB.rb
require_relative 'netscaler'

ips = Netscaler.list_ips
puts ips # script B may show these ips on the screen
...    

#scriptA.rb
require_relative 'netscaler'

ips = Netscaler.list_ips
# script A will not show them. Instead it will operate on the returned result.
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advices and for the solution. Everything is working well now! I never used classes in ruby before nor did I ever do a require_relative. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks to execute script B and return the output:

```
ip_list = `scriptB`.split("\n")
```

This can be plugged into Alex's organizational suggestion. I would do this if script B is a non-Ruby script that you don't control.

Note that if there is any leading or trailing whitespace you can add a `.map(&:strip)` to the end.